# Changing data type to column that is part of clustered primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I need to change data type of column which is part of clustered key
I saw in posts that the best way is to create a new column with desired type, move data there from original column, and then drop original column and rename new column to  the name of the original column.
My question is, will it be problematic, as this column is part of primary key?
How to do this without removing/ adding the PK?
Thanks,

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ff
ADD SSN binary(32) NOT NULL

--set encrypted data
UPDATE dbo.ff
   SET SSN = [dbo].[gg(PassId)

ALTER TABLE dbo.ff
DROP COLUMN PassId

EXEC sp_RENAME '[dbo].[ff].SSN' , 'PassId', 'COLUMN'

END
GO
```

Comment: Drop constraint(s) and index(es) that reference the column, alter column, add constraint(s) and index(es).

Comment: [It is not trivial](https://am2.co/2019/12/changing-a-column-from-int-to-bigint-without-downtime/) unless you can have downtime to make the change.

Comment: Using a binary (and encrypted) column in PK sounds a bit weird to my ears. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (correct as you want) it is possible to do so without removing or adding the primary key constraint

```
--ADD A NEW COLUMN
--THEN WE UPDATE THIS table
--THEN UPDATE PRIMARY KEY
--DROP ORIGINAL COLUMN
--AND RENAME NEW COLUMN
ALTER TABLE dbo.ff
ADD NewColumn binary(32) NOT NULL;

UPDATE dbo.ff
SET NewColumn = [dbo].[gg(PassId)];

ALTER TABLE dbo.ff
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ff;
ALTER TABLE dbo.ff
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ff PRIMARY KEY (NewColumn);

ALTER TABLE dbo.ff
DROP COLUMN PassId;

EXEC sp_RENAME '[dbo].[ff].NewColumn' , 'PassId', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: `without removing or adding the primary key constraint` -> what? Your script explicitly says `DROP PK/ADD PK`. The problem here is that sometimes this requires changing other indexes and foreign keys that point at this table first. If this is your only table and it's small, ok, probably fine, but in a more elaborate system this doesn't do what you suggest.

Comment: Thanks. But is not a pk of one field. It is part of pk with several fields.